# Transmit WebRTC video to streaming server

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, webrtc, video-editing

I'm working on web app, where two of users have videochat conversation, and all other users receive stream with overlapped video and audio of this chat. P2P connection of all this users seems to require too much traffic, so I want to transmit user's video to my VPS, then overlap it, and then transmit it again to streaming server (e.g. youtube). I've read about WebRTC native code library, so I can write my own server-side code, but I wondering if there any working solution.

Comment: You can look into using a [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) _pipeline_ where you would do the video signal overlaying and then pipe the GStreamer output to your WebRTC application.

Comment: You are asking for any working solution.
WebRTC Kurento media server (open source) can slove you task.
Some uses cases here [link](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introducing_kurento.html)

You can realize schemas of stream:
One to one, One to many, Many to many

On server side, you can transcode or restream video

Comment: @DenisLisitskiy thanks, I've already found this one. I'll add answer for my question when I arrange this with the customer and try it out